# Double definition of IVsUIShell5

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, com-interop, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to do simply the following:

```
this.GetService(typeof(IVsUIShell5))
```

But there is no chance to have the service, as I got this error:

> Embedded interop type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIShell5' is defined in both 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0' and 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ReferenceManager.Providers.dll'. Some operations on objects of this type are not supported while debugging. Consider casting this object to type 'dynamic' when debugging or building with the 'Embed Interop Types' property set to false.

Any idea? I  cannot even understand the error.

The *Embed Interop Types* property is set to `False`.

Comment: I workarounded the problem doing a using like this:
    using MyIVsUIShell5 = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIShell5;
Unfortunately now the value returned by the GetService is null. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I solved in this way.

```
using IVsUIShell5 = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIShell5;
......
IVsUIShell5 shell5 = (IVsUIShell5)this.GetService(typeof(IVsUIShell));
```

I hope it helps!